# Textbox doesn't align to top

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

to get the scenario, I've uploaded a picture

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MpriCub.png].

The red textbox is an item of the `dockpanel` (Code below). Furthermore, is the dockpanel part of another dockpanel.

```
<DockPanel
    Height="100">
    <TextBox 
        DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Background="Red"
        Margin="5"/>

</DockPanel>
```

My aim is to align the textbox to the top. Have someone an idea? As you can see, I already set the DockPanel.Dock to the "Top".

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add VerticalAlignment to the TextBox as well, like that:

```
<DockPanel Height="200">
            <TextBox 
                Height="50"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="Red"
                Margin="5"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`DockPanel`s have a property called `LastChildFill` which is default `true`, setting this to `false` should fix your problem

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you set the LastChildFill property to true, which is the default
>   setting, the last child element of a DockPanel always fills the
>   remaining space, regardless of any other dock value that you set on
>   the last child element. To dock a child element in another direction,
>   you must set the LastChildFill property to false and must also specify
>   an explicit dock direction on the last child element.

and since your textbox is the only child of the DockPanel it's also the last child

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately the result with your soultion was not as expected. I set the VerticalAlignment to "Top" in the DockPanel which works.